# nokogiri will change node attribute when use add_child

Tags: android, ruby, nokogiri

here is [my full code](https://gist.github.com/61402f1001ea289d0e5a4956d5fd065b), here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'nokogiri'

d = Nokogiri.parse(File.read(File.expand_path("../am.xml", __FILE__)))
perms = d.css('uses-permission')

d2 = Nokogiri.parse(File.read(File.expand_path("../am2.xml", __FILE__)))
d2.css('manifest')[0].add_child(perms)
puts d2
```

the old  is

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

but `puts d2` output:

```
<uses-permission name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I hope `puts d2` output "android:name=", how to fix it?

Comment: It's not possible to replicate the problem because you haven't given us the code for `ro_misc`, or the XML files in _the question itself_. Please read "[mcve]". You're better off using `Nokogiri::XML(File.open('some file.xml'))` or the HTML equivalent, rather than make Nokogiri try to decide whether it's XML or HTML. I've seen Nokogiri get confused using `Nokogiri.parse`.

Comment: @theTinMan sorry, my code don't need ro_misc, I have update my code

Comment: It's still not obvious what you're trying to do. Perhaps, as "[mcve]" says, supplying the _minimal_ input XML and your expected output XML will clarify. Read the links in "[ask]" as they'll help you understand about asking also and provide useful ideas and tips.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I force specific added content with Node or NodeSet `to_s`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'ro_misc/exe'
include RoMisc::Exe

d = Nokogiri.parse(File.read(File.expand_path("../am.xml", __FILE__)))
perms = d.css('uses-permission')

d2 = Nokogiri.parse(File.read(File.expand_path("../am2.xml", __FILE__)))
d2.css('manifest')[0].add_child(perms.to_s)
puts d2
```

The reason is, this method it will change attribute include ":"

```
  def add_child_node_and_reparent_attrs node # :nodoc:
    add_child_node node
    node.attribute_nodes.find_all { |a| a.name =~ /:/ }.each do |attr_node|
      attr_node.remove
      node[attr_node.name] = attr_node.value
    end
  end
```

The reason is, Node#attribute doesn't parse "android:name" as "name". I override `Nokogiri::XML::Node#add_child_node_and_reparent_attrs`, and use a regex to parse the node attribute:

```
  def add_child_node_and_reparent_attrs node # :nodoc:
    # here is a bug, if attr key is android:name, node.attribute_nodes will return name, so i should parse attrs by my self
    attrs = {}
    node.to_s.match(%r{<.*>}).to_s.scan(%r{(\S+)=(['"])(.*?)\2}) do |k, _, v|
      attrs[k] = v
    end

    add_child_node node

    attrs2 = node.attributes
    being_rm_attrs = (attrs2 - attrs)

    attrs2.each do |k, _|
      node.remove_attribute(k)
    end

    being_added_attrs = attrs - attrs2

    being_added_attrs.each do |k, v|
      node.set_attribute(k, v)
    end
    node
  end
```

Comment: It's good that you found a solution, however it's very unlikely that you actually needed to change a core method for Nokogiri to do it. I've written a lot of Nokogiri code and haven't ever needed anything like that. When editing a question or answer, please don't add "Edit" or "Update" tags. SO has a history available so we can see every change. Instead, incorporate the change as if it'd been part of the original text. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255644/128421